# Why is $Z_t$ uncorrelated with $X_{t-1}$ in $X_t=\theta X_{t-1}+Z_t$?

Tags: time-series, variance, arima

In a solution to the problem below, the teaching assistant solves it by calculating $\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]$ and ends up with also having to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}Z_t]$ after expanding the square. To do this, he states that $\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}Z_t]=0$ since $X_{t-1}$ is independent of $Z_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ is uncorrelated with $Z_t$.

**Questions:**

1. Why is $X_{t-1}$ independent of $Z_t$? I don't see that we assume that the TS is casual.
2. Why is $X_{t-1}$ uncorrelated with $Z_t$?

**Problem:**

> Let a timeseries model $X:=(X_t, t\in\mathbb{Z})$ be given by
>
> $$X_t=\phi X_{t-1}+Z_t, \quad \text{where} \quad Z_t\sim
>  \text{WN}(0,\sigma^2)\quad \text{and} \quad |\phi|\neq 1.$$
>
> Assume that the stochastic process satisfying this model is stationary. Compute the variance of $X.$

**Note:** Yes, I know that one simply can calculate $\text{Var}[X_t]$ directly in one line, but I'm trying to understand the motivations behind the instructors steps.

Comment: I suspect that $Z_t$ is *assumed* to be i.i.d., and independent of $X_t$ (and therefore also of the other $X_s, s< t$ in case this holds for $X_0$) without this being explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Q2: Independent $\Rightarrow$ uncorrelated.

Comment: To get $\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}Z_t]=0$, in addition to independent/uncorrelated you need $\mathbb{E}[X_{t-1}]=0$ or $\mathbb{E}[Z_t]=0$

Comment: @Lewian I think $Z_t$ not independent of $X_t$ but it is assumed to be independent of $X_s$ for $s<t$ including $X_{t-1}$

Comment: @Henry $Z_t \sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$ seems to allow the assumption that $E[Z_t] = 0.$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Indeed it does

Comment: I think you need $|\phi| < 1$, not $|\phi| \neq 1$, in your problem statement.

Comment: @Henry: Yes, you're right, didn't think long enough.

Comment: @DilipSarwate - No I double checked, it says in the problem that $|\phi| \neq 1$. So I guess one has to compute it in both the casual and non-casual case. Although there is a chance its a misprint in the question.

Comment: @Parseval "causal" nor "casual" and I have edited my answer to discuss what happens when $|\phi|>1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general meaning of white noise (that's what that WN denotes) is that the  random variables $Z_t$ are independent. Some statisticians claim that it suffices to assume that the $Z_t$'s are *uncorrelated* (zero-mean, finite variance $\sigma^2$) random variables, that is,
$$\operatorname{cov}(Z_t, Z_{t^\prime}) = \begin{cases}\sigma^2, & t = t^\prime,\\0, & t \neq t^\prime\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
but some others (including your teaching assistant and non-statisticians such as myself) prefer the stronger requirement that the $Z_t$'s be *independent* (zero-mean, finite variance $\sigma^2$) random variables; i.i.d. random variables if you are familiar with the acronym. Of course, $(1)$ still holds when the $Z_t$'s are independent.  As your TA says, $X_{t-1}$ is independent of $Z_t$.

Actually, if you *iterate* the defining equation to write
\begin{align}
X_t &= \phi X_{t-1} + Z_t\\
&= \phi \big(\phi X_{t-2} + Z_{t-1}\big)  + Z_t\\
&= \phi^2 X_{t-2} + \phi Z_{t-1}  + Z_t\\
&= \phi^2 \big(\phi X_{t-3}  + Z_{t-2}\big)+ \phi Z_{t-1}  + Z_t\\
&= \phi^3 X_{t-3} + \phi^2 Z_{t-2} + \phi Z_{t-1}  + Z_t
\end{align}
and so on, you can use induction to deduce that
$X_t = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi^n Z_{t-n}$ and so , since the $Z_{t-n}$'s are independent random variables,
$$\operatorname{var}(Z_t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{var}(\phi^nZ_{t-n}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi^{2n} \operatorname{var}(Z_{t-n}) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi^{2n} \sigma^2 =\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2} \tag{2}$$
provided that $|\phi|<1$.  If $|\phi| > 1$, that series in $(2)$ diverges and it is not possible to write the value of $\operatorname{var}(Z_t)$ in the form shown on the right side of $(2)$. To answer a secondary question raised by the OP in a comment, it is not necessary to define a $X_0$ separately; the problem statement says that $t \in \mathbb Z$ and so $Z_t$ is defined for all integers $t$. Note that your TA's claim that $X_{t-1}$ is independent of $Z_t$ is perfectly valid: $X_{t-1}$ is a weighted sum of $Z_{t-1}, Z_{t-2}, \ldots$ and is thus independent of $Z_t$ by definition (uncorrelated with $Z_t$ for the naysayers).

Comment: Probably as perfect of an explanation as I could have hoped for. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: Some question: You say that $Z_t$ are independent of any other random variables in the system. Does this mean that $Z_t$ is independent of $X_t$ as well? Clearly  the value of $X_t$ depends on $Z_t$ in the first equation in your array? Also, to make that recursion work, don't you need a value for $X_0?$

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I still don't understand if and why $Z_t$ is independent of $X_t$.

Comment: @Parseval $Z_t$ and $X_t$ are not independent; $Z_t$ and $X_{t-1}$ are independent.

Comment: Nice answer,+1. Is there a reason why you prefer independence over uncorrelated? It doesn’t seem to matter for this question. What applications do you have in mind that make you prefer independence?

Comment: @Kevin Let $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $\{Z_n\}$ a collection of iid random variables taking on values $\pm 1$ with equal probability $\frac 12$, independent of $X$. Define $Y_n=XZ_n$. Then, $Y_n\sim N(0,1)$ and for $n\neq m$, $E[Y_nY_m]=E[X^2]E[Z_n]E[Z_m]=0$ and so the $Y_n$'s constitute a white (Gaussian) noise process according to the naysayers.  But, given $Y_n=y$, we know that _all_ the $Y_m$ necessarily have value $\pm y$ !! I think this is a shoddy model for white Gaussian noise, but ymmv. Why insist on hair-splitting between uncorrelated white noise and independent white noise which (continued)

Comment: (continued) ... the _cognoscenti_ on this forum prefer when just defining (discrete-time) white noise is a sequence of iid random variables with distributions symmetric about $0$ saves everyone a lot of grief?  The uncorrelated white noise concept is usefully only for linear or OLS regression, but not for  more general purposes, so why insist on it?